# query next () not working in quiz

Tags: jquery

This is a quiz and I'm using show/hide within one page to reveal each question as they complete it.

The next() for the ".question" element is not working properly and I've tried several different ways.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

```js
$(document).ready( function() {

$("#quizHome").show();
 
$("#begin").on('click', function () {
    $("#quizHome").hide();
    $(".question:first").show();
});

  $(".question:first button").on('click', function (){
     $(".question:first").hide();
      $(this).closest(".question:first").next().show();
});
  
 
 $(".price").hide();
 $("button").on('mouseenter', function() {
  $(this).closest('.box').find('.blue').addClass('samColor');
 });
 $("button").on('mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).closest('.box').find('.blue').removeClass('samColor');
 });
 $("button").on('click', function() {
  $('.box').removeClass('transBox');
  $(this).closest('.box').addClass('transBox');
 });
 $(".sale").on('click',function() {
  $(".price").fadeIn().show();
 });
 

var accumValue = 0;

$("button").on('click', function() {

    if(!$(this).attr('value')) {
        return;
    }

    accumValue += parseInt($(this).attr('value'), 10);
});

$('#finalbutton').on('click', function() {
if (accumValue <=25) {
  $("#bkgHome").hide();
  $("#question1").hide();
  $("#question2").hide();
  $("#question3").hide();
  $("#question4").hide();
  $("#question5").hide();
  $("#question6").hide();
  $("#question7").hide();
  $("#results").hide();
  $("#captain").show();
  $("#ironMan").hide();
  $("#blackWidow").hide();

} else if (accumValue > 25 && accumValue <= 70) {
  $("#bkgHome").hide();
  $("#question1").hide();
  $("#question2").hide();
  $("#question3").hide();
  $("#question4").hide();
  $("#question5").hide();
  $("#question6").hide();
  $("#question7").hide();
  $("#results").hide();
  $("#captain").hide();
  $("#ironMan").show();
  $("#blackWidow").hide();
} else {
  $("#bkgHome").hide();
  $("#question1").hide();
  $("#question2").hide();
  $("#question3").hide();
  $("#question4").hide();
  $("#question5").hide();
  $("#question6").hide();
  $("#question7").hide();
  $("#results").hide();
  $("#captain").hide();
  $("#ironMan").hide();
  $("#blackWidow").show();
}});  

});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#bkgHome {
   background-image: url(images/texture-1.jpg);
}

#bkg1 {
   background-image: url(images/texture-1.jpg);
}
#bkg2 {
   background-image: url(images/texture-1.jpg);
}
#bkg3 {
   background-image: url(images/texture-1.jpg);
}
#bkg4 {
   background-image: url(images/texture-1.jpg);
}
#bkg5 {
   background-image: url(images/texture-1.jpg);
}
#bkg6 {
   background-image: url(images/texture-1.jpg);
}
#bkg7 {
   background-image: url(images/texture-1.jpg);
}
#bkg8 {
   background-image: url(images/texture-1.jpg);
}
#bkg9 {
   background-image: url(images/texture-1.jpg);
}
#bkg10 {
   background-image: url(images/texture-1.jpg);
}
#quizHome {
 width:100%;
 height:800px;
 text-align:center;
  display:none;
}
.question {
 width:100%;
 height:800px;
 text-align:center;
   display:none;
}


.results {
 width:100%;
 height:800px;
 text-align:center;
   display:none;
}

h1, h2 {
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
li {
  list-style-type:none;
}
.box {
 width: 250px;
 height: 250px;
 background-color:rgba(102,102,102,0.7);
 display:inline-block;
 margin-right:50px;
 text-align:center;
 padding-top:25px;
 line-height:40px;
 padding-bottom:25px;
 box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(5,5,5,0.6);
 border-radius: 20px;
 
}
.transBox {
 width: 250px;
 height: 250px;
 background-color:rgba(58,57,57,0.8);
 display:inline-block;
 margin-right:50px;
 text-align:center;
}

.city {
 font-size: 18px;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

}
.blue {
 background-color: rgba(90,19,17,0.6);
 width:150px;
 height: 40px;
 font-size:15px;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 border-radius: 10px;

}
.samColor {
 background-color:rgba(18,17,23,0.6);;
 width:150px;
 height: 40px;
 font-size:18px;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 border-radius: 10px;
 color:#ffffff;


}


.thumbs {
 border-radius:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="bkgHome">
<div id="quizHome">
 <ul>
    <li class="box one">
      <ul>
       <li class="photos">
          <span class="city">Are you ready?</span>
       </li>
      </ul>
     <button class="blue" id="begin" value="0">BEGIN</button>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>

<div id="bkg1">
<div class="question">
<h1>Which character are you? Total:</h1>
 <ul>
    <li class="box one">
      <ul>
       <li class="photos">
          <span class="city">Being in high places.</span>
        <img src="images/heights.jpg" class="thumbs" width="100">
       </li>
      </ul>
     <button class="blue" id="scary_height" value="5">ANSWER  1</button>
    </li>
    <li class ="box two">
            <ul>
       <li class="photos">
       <span class="city">Being in small spaces.</span>
        <img src="images/smallSpace.jpg" class="thumbs" width="100">
       </li>
     <button class="blue" id="small_space" value="10">ANSWER 2</button>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class = "box three">
      <ul>
       <li class="photos">
          <span class="city">The fear of wild fire.</span>
        <img src="images/fire.jpg" class="thumbs" width="100">
       </li>
      </ul>
     <button class="blue" id="scary_fire" value="15">ANSWER  3</button>
    </li>
    <li class = "box four">
      <ul>
       <li class="photos">
          <span class="city">Being around scary animals.</span>
        <img src="images/scaryAnimals.jpg" class="thumbs" width="100">
       </li>
      </ul>
     <button class="blue" id="scary_animals"value="20">ANSWER  4</button>
    </li>
 </ul>
</div>
</div>


<div id="bkg2">
<div class="question">
<h1>Which character are you?</h1>
 <ul>
    <li class="box one">
     <h2>QUESTION 2 </h2>
     <button class="blue" id="goat" value="5">ANSWER  1</button>
      <ul>
       <li class="photos">
          <span class="city">Being in high places.</span>
        <img src="images/heights.jpg" class="thumbs" width="100">
       </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class ="box two">
     <h2>Box Two <span class="price"> $100</span></h2>
     <button class="blue" id="bird" value="10">ANSWER 2</button>
            <ul>
       <li class="photos">
       <span class="city">Being in small spaces.</span>
        <img src="images/smallSpace.jpg" class="thumbs" width="100">
       </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class = "box three">
     <h2>Box Two <span class="price"> $100</span></h2>
     <button class="blue" id="fish" value="15">ANSWER  3</button>
      <ul>
       <li class="photos">
          <span class="city">The fear of wild fire.</span>
        <img src="images/fire.jpg" class="thumbs" width="100">
       </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class = "box four">
     <h2>Box Two <span class="price"> $100</span></h2>
     <button class="blue" id="snake" value="20">ANSWER  4</button>
      <ul>
       <li class="photos">
          <span class="city">Being around scary animals.</span>
        <img src="images/scaryAnimals.jpg" class="thumbs" width="100">
       </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
</div>
</div>


<div id="bkg3">
<div class="question">
<h1>Which character are you?</h1>
 <ul>
    <li class="box one">
     <h2>QUESTION 3 <span class="price"> $100</span></h2>
     <button class="blue" value="5">ANSWER  1</button>
      <ul>
       <li class="photos">
          <span class="city">Being in high places.</span>
        <img src="images/heights.jpg" class="thumbs" width="100">
       </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class ="box two">
     <h2>Box Two <span class="price"> $100</span></h2>
     <button class="blue" value="10">ANSWER 2</button>
            <ul>
       <li class="photos">
       <span class="city">Being in small spaces.</span>
        <img src="images/smallSpace.jpg" class="thumbs" width="100">
       </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class = "box three">
     <h2>Box Two <span class="price"> $100</span></h2>
     <button class="blue" value="15">ANSWER  3</button>
      <ul>
       <li class="photos">
          <span class="city">The fear of wild fire.</span>
        <img src="images/fire.jpg" class="thumbs" width="100">
       </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class = "box four">
     <h2>Box Two <span class="price"> $100</span></h2>
     <button class="blue" value="20">ANSWER  4</button>
      <ul>
       <li class="photos">
          <span class="city">Being around scary animals.</span>
        <img src="images/scaryAnimals.jpg" class="thumbs" width="100">
       </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
 <button id="finalbutton">Get Results</button>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the jQuery documentation, it states that `.next()` will `get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements.`

You can't select `$(".question:first").next()` because `$(".question:first")` does not have any siblings. Take a closer look at your HTML.

http://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: I tried several different ways.  I've adjusted the html and input this new jquery code but its still not working correctly: 
$("button").on('click', function () {
    $("#quizHome").hide();
 $(this).parents().find($(".question").first()).show();
  $(this).next(".question").show();
});

But to see it all in action, I've posted it here in Codepen: http://codepen.io/smeeker/pen/dPWwvZ